# Spreadsheet formula extract zip code from address

Tags: google-sheets

I have cells in column A that contain info as shown below, where the property address includes a zip code. This zip code can be one of seven different option, but always 5 digits.

I need a function that says:

> IF the cell contains `zipcode1`, `zipcode2`, `zipcode3`, etc., then copy that zipcode to the next cell over.

Any help?

```
Dispatch Type: ********      

Service Fee Due :   ********  

Urgency      : ********       

Service Fee Paid:     ********

Net To Collect  :   ********

Dispatch ID  : ********

Dispatch Date: ********

Item 17822 : ********  

Customer: ********

Property Address: ********

Dispatch Contact(s):
```

Comment: You can do that with REGEXEXTRACT() formula or js regex method

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting answers for this - because I don't find the question clear enough to understand what you're looking for. You should clarify: Is all that data in _one_ cell? Is there a column of identifies and a column of data? Can you show a typical example of data for Property Address?

Answer (score 3):

As a first attempt, in cell B1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"(?i)zipcode"),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"[0-9]{5})),))`